# Changing cell values based on another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Lets say that I have 3 parameters/cells:

- High (Cell A1)
- Medium (Cell A2)
- Low (Cell A3)

the fixed values for these cells are 2, 2 ,2

how can I change the value of cellA1 based on the changes of cellA2, or cellA3.
for example:
if cellA2 value is 1, I have to add 1 to cellA1, and if its Zero I have to add 2 to ceelA1.

can you help please?

Comment: Simple changes can be tracked like this.
in cell A2 put this
=A1+1

Its possible to put complicated ones as well

Comment: @Naresh : I would -1 that comment if I could. OP asks for conditional logic. Your formula breaks on his second case (if it's zero).

Comment: @toti You need to tell us a bit more. How many conditions or statuses are there ? Is it only cell A1 that you will modify and expect the other cells to follow ? What should happen if the value entered is something else than 0 or 1 ?

Comment: Also, what did you already try?

Comment: Are A2 or A3 dependent upon other cells as well?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

The A cells have formula's & you would enter values in the B cells.  Based upon the formulas below is B2 way 2 then A2 would be 2 & A1 would be 2.  If B2 was 1 then A2 would be 1 & A3 would be 3.

```
A1 formula: =(2-A2)+B1
A2 formula: =B2
A3 formula: =B3
```